# How to solve the problem of kartik datePicker with bootstrap4 in Yii2?

Tags: bootstrap-4, datepicker, yii2, kartik-v

I installed yii2, (installed automatically yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap4), then installed kartik-v/yii2-widget-datepicker then this error comes out:

Invalid Configuration – yii\base\InvalidConfigException You must install ‘yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap’ extension for Bootstrap 3.x version support. Dependency to ‘yii2-bootstrap’ has not been included with ‘yii2-krajee-base’. To resolve, you must add ‘yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap’ to the ‘require’ section of your application’s composer.json file and then run ‘composer update’.

NOTE: This dependency change has been done since v2.0 of ‘yii2-krajee-base’ because only one of ‘yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap’ OR ‘yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap4’ OR ‘yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap5’ extensions can be installed. The developer can thus choose and control which bootstrap extension library to install.

I am not getting what to do with this problem.

Comment: Did you try to set bootstrap version in config? Try adding `'bsVersion' => '4.x'` to `params` section in your config.

Answer (score 0):

Just added `bsVersion => '4.x'` in the params section of the `config` and its working. It is used to support the `bootstrap 4` version.